# Ember 3 conditional statement

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Why while this code does render,

```
{{#if ordered}}
<ol>
  {{#each things as |thing|}}
    <li {{action "showThing" thing}}>{{thing}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ol>
{{else}}
<ul>
  {{#each things as |thing|}}
    <li {{action "showThing" thing}}>{{thing}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
{{/if}}
```

this does not?

```
{{{if ordered "<ol>" "<ul>"}}}
  {{#each things as |thing|}}
    <li {{action "showThing" thing}}>{{thing}}</li>
  {{/each}}
{{{if ordered "</ol>" "</ul>"}}}
```

The last snippet emits `<ol></ol>` before the list and no closing tag after the list:

```
<div id="ember260" class="ember-view"><h2>Ordered List Of Things</h2>
<ol></ol>
    <li data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-261="261">yarn</li>
    <li data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-262="262">feathers</li>
    <li data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-263="263">dinner plate</li>
    <li data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-264="264">sheep</li>
</div>
```

and why does this code not even compile?

```
{{#if ordered}}
<ol>
{{else}}
<ul>
{{/if}}
  {{#each things as |thing|}}
    <li {{action "showThing" thing}}>{{thing}}</li>
  {{/each}}
{{#if ordered}}
</ol>
{{else}}
</ul>
{{/if}}
```

Error:

> Unclosed element `ol` (on line 2).

Comment: `{{{if` to the extent of my knowledge is not a thing, `{{{` in handlebars is used to renderer the contents of the variable without escaping the content.
As for your second question you cannot have your html tags wrapped in conditions, what you could do is create a component that handles the logic of the tagName based on `ordered` and have the loop within the component's block form.

Answer (score 3):

I am writing the code what PatsyIssa mentioned in his comments,

Create component named `ordered-list`.

```
{{ordered-list tagName=(if (eq ordered 'ol' 'ul')) things=things showThings=(action 'showThings')}}
```

In ordered-list.hbs,

```
{{#each things as |thing|}}
    <li {{action showThing thing}}>{{thing}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

For the `eq` helper you need to install [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) addon or create your own helper that simply compares values.